# Add Option Tag with value to empty Select Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this element in my Code(added with jquery, works fine):
    `<span id='userProfileHiddenSelectBox' class='profileItem'><select disabled><option value='no' selected>-No hidden contents-</option></select></span>`
After that this option is removed and some other options were put into the select tag, which is now enabled.
Maybe later(Depends on user interaction), the other options were removed, the select is disabled and i am trying to put the old option-tag inside again.
This works, if it has no value Attribute(but i need it for some other code).
But if i add the value attribute (I tried jquery .val('theValue'), .attr('value','theValue') and add it with the option element) the option tag disappears on the screen and in the code(firefox inspector or google chrome dev tools). I don't know what happened.

Thank you for some help.

Comment: Could you post how you are re-adding this option? Or replicate with a fiddle perhaps?

Comment: It's a bit weird, but whilst i was writing the code to my question i changed one thing in my code, i don't understand it, because there's an element selected, which isn't really there, but now it works, so sorry about my question, its my first question, how can i say that it is "closed" or something? Thank you for your comment, otherwise i would search for hours for this error ;).

Answer (score 0):

Could always try using full html when replacing the contents of the select. I personally haven't played much with values, but this appears to work:

```
$("selector").html("<option value='no' selected>-No hidden contents-</option>");
```

While I understand that this is probably not the best way to go about it, it can do in a pinch.

Comment: I have done it like this before, but there was something i don't understand(comment under the question), but thank you anyway ;).